# Pass variable to @Optional Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to pass object pathToJsonFileAppCreate as an optional parameter using @Optional annotation.

```
 public static final String pathToJsonFileAppCreate = fprUploadBundle.getString("pathToJsonFile");

 @Parameters({"pathToJsonFileAppCreate"})
 @BeforeSuite
    public void SuiteSetup(@Optional(pathToJsonFileAppCreate) String pathToJsonFileAppCreate) {
```

Although the object should be constant (see the declaration), I'm still getting error : "element value must be a constant expression"
Basically I'm trying to load value either from property file (in case of no parameter value defined in xml) or from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are evaluated at compile time. You say that the `object should be constant`, but that's apparently not the case

```
pathToJsonFileAppCreate = fprUploadBundle.getString("pathToJsonFile");
```

Compiler cannot know what will get returned at run-time. 
If you think the value is constant, then put that constant there.

You could theoretically modify the value at runtime(https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params), but you would have to make sure you do that before whatever is using these annotations have not run yet.

Anyway it looks like you're misusing the annotation. What is the library the annotation comes from?

Comment: They even have it written in the javadoc: https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/annotations/Optional.html
`Java annotation parameters can only be ConstantExpressions, which can be primitive/string literals`